# Case Condition in Python with Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I've been learning pandas for a couple of days. I am migrating a SQL DB to PYTHON and have encountered the sql statement (example):

```
select * from
table_A a
left join table_B b
on a.ide = b.ide
and a.credit_type = case when b.type > 0 then b.credit_type else a.credit_type end
```

I've only been able to migrate to the first condition. My difficulty is in the last line and I don't know how to migrate it. Tables are actually sql queries that I've stored in dataframes.

```
merge = pd.merge(df_query_a, df_query_b),on='ide', how='left')
```

any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Case condition is like an if-then-else statement, which you can implement in Pandas using [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) like below:

Based on left join resulting dataframe `merge`:

```
import numpy as np

merge['credit_type_x'] = np.where(merge['type_y'] > 0, merge['credit_type_y'], merge['credit_type_x'])
```

Here the column names `credit_type_x` `credit_type_y` should have been created on the Pandas merge function after renaming conflicting (same) column names on the 2 sources dataframes.  In case dataframe `merge` doesn't have the column `type_y` because column `type` appears only on Table_B but not on Table_A, you can use column name `type` here instead.

Alternatively, as you just need to modify the value of `credit_type_x` only when `type_y > 0` and retain the value of `credit_type_x` without modification if  NOT `type_y > 0`, we can also do it simply by:

```
merge.loc[merge['type_y'] > 0, 'credit_type_x'] = merge['credit_type_y']
```

Comment: thank you @SeaBean , I used the first suggestion. When I wanted to use the second I had the error: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Comment: @Tom  The error for the second suggestion is just a warning, you should most probably still get the result you want since the `.loc` is on a Pandas Series (a column) rather than the whole DataFrame.  Anyway, to avoid that warning, you can slightly change the syntax as per my latest edit above.  Anyway, either one of the 2 suggestions should be fine for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Below two options to face your problem

1. You can add a column in df_query_a based on the condition that you need considering two dataframes, and after that, make the merge.
2. You can try with some library as [pandasql3](https://pypi.org/project/pandasql3/).